# Running rails console with bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I execute `bundle exec rails c` I get a ruby console with the following prompt

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
jruby-1.6.3 :001 >
```

Everything looks in order but when I use the ↑ ↓ arrows to pull my previous command I get `^[[A^[[B` output into my console.

Running rails console without bundle exec works fine. Any reason as to why this is? Is bundle exec starting up some new faux shell?

Comment: What are your OS and terminal program? Also, if using an unix OS do you have a `.inputrc` in your home dir?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this after installing jruby 1.6.3, on linux with zsh

Comment: Did you get around to fixing this? I'd be interested in the root cause if you know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like bundler prevents the irb console from using readline. You can work around this by putting the following line in your `.irbrc`, which will force irb to use readline:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
```

Comment: This is obviously a hack, I suggest you file a bug with bundler here: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues

Comment: Thanks Benoit, this helped me with Rails 2.3.8 and JRuby 1.6.7 on a Linux Precise/Unity machine. I copied your remark but linked to your original post, hope no offense taken. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760564/command-history-in-rails-console-over-putty/12922308#12922308