# command history in Rails console over PuTTY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, putty

Using script/console in rails 2.3.12 over PuTTY. When I press the "up" arrow to access the last command I wrote, instead of bringing up the command it just prints the weird string "^[[A" to the terminal. Same with other arrows...back arrow prints "^[[D" and forward arrow prints "^[[C"

Hoping somebody recognizes these weird codes, and can possibly tell me how to get the arrows working properly. Is this a PuTTY settings issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The up-arrow functionality is supplied by [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Typically, when ruby is built, ./configure auto-detects the readline libraries and builds ruby mappings to them. Sometimes this doesn't work and you have to install new libraries or custom configure --with-readline-dir when building ruby. irb and rails-console just use the readline capability of the ruby stdlib, soyour problem is likely that your ruby build didn't detect and bind readline.

I suggest you survey the [other SO questions relevant to building ruby with readline](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=readline+support+ruby&submit=search) to see if one of them gives you guidance for your version of ruby and your OS.

Answer (score 2):

I used this, and it worked for me with JRuby 1.6.7 and Rails 2.3.8 (see link for original solution)

It looks like bundler prevents the irb console from using readline. You can work around this by putting the following line in your `.irbrc`, which will force irb to use readline:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
```

as suggested here

[Running rails console with bundle exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162756/running-rails-console-with-bundle-exec)

hope this helps.